# Check a value with loop and list - Python

Tags: python

I made this to test it for another script.
I have this code that checks if a specific value in users.txt I added it (let's say `21`) exists the check function value `21` if it's, then it prints the existing value
But no result with it, where is the problem?

```
listNum = list(range(1, 101))


def check(z):
    with open('users.txt') as f:
        for i in range(len(listNum)): 
            if str(i) in f.read():
                result = print(str(listNum[i]))
                return result

check(21)
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the returned value. And `print()` returns `None`, so `result` is `None` in any case.

Comment: @Guy Can you please give a small example, I'm fresh at python

Comment: can you share a file example and the precise expected output ?

Comment: @azro the file example has one value which is `21`, The output must be the value that is in the example file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you consume the text file each time you perform `f.read()`. So in your loop you are not checking if all your numbers are in the file, but only if the very first is in your file, because for the seconds and all following numbers your `f.read` will result in an empty string, because the end-of-file was already reached.

Try storing the file content instead, like this:

```
def check(z):
    with open('users.txt') as f:
        file_content= f.read()
    for i in range(len(listNum)): 
        if str(i) in file_content:
            result = str(listNum[i])
            print(result)
            return result

check(21)
```

Btw. you don't need to use range objects to iterate over lists. It's more pythonic to do it like this:

```
def check(z):
    with open('users.txt') as f:
        file_content= f.read()
    for num in listNum: 
        if str(num) in file_content:
            result = print(num)
            return str(num)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, There's a little small problem, if there's a value like `32` in users.txt it takes only `3` value. How can I fix that

Comment: You mean, 3 also matches 32? there are more possibilities to solve that and it depens on the format of your input file which is the best / most convenient to do so. If it is a comma separated list of numbers you can parse it like that, if it is something like a plain text file that contains numbers, you'd probably better use regular expressions.